# Check if there are no repeats in the list

Tags: c#, list, contains

I have a list called com, which contains a bunch of integers. I need to check the list to make sure that each integer only exists once in the list.
So if:

```
com{1,2,3,4,1,3}
```

I need have some code to check that 1 is represented twice as well as 3.
This is my best guess on how to solve it:

```
for (int j = 0; j < com.Count; j++)
        {
            if (com.Contains(com[j]))
            {
                lion += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                lion = 0;
            }   
        }
```

But it doesn't work. Can anybody out there help me??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple, but probably not that efficient way using LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

...

bool containsRepeats = com.Count() != com.Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: If you want to know what is repeated see [pratapchandra's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8340951/593627).

Comment: You are my hero.. I have spend the last 3 hours trying to find a way to check it...

Answer (score 2):

You can determine if a collection contains a duplicate by adding each item to a [HashSet<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx). The [HashSet<T>.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) returns false if the item is already present:

```
public static bool HasDuplicate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var h = new HashSet<int>();
    return source.Any(x => !h.Add(x));
}
```

---

If you just want to remove all duplicates from the collection, you can use the [Enumerable.Distinct Extension Method:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx)

```
var result = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3 }.Distinct();
// result == { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

Comment: +1 because i'd imagine it's more efficient that my method as it's an early-out.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this..

```
int[] listOfItems = new[] { 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 4, 3 };
var duplicates = listOfItems
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key);
foreach (var d in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is for methods to do so:

```
public static bool LinqAny<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new();

    return enumerable.Any(element => !set.Add(element));
}

public static bool LinqAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    HashSet<T> set = new();

    return !enumerable.All(set.Add);
}

public static bool LinqDistinct<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.Distinct().Count() != enumerable.Count();
}

public static bool ToHashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.ToHashSet().Count != enumerable.Count();
}
```